# Invoke EJB's 2.x from Spring

Tags: spring

Is it possible to access services provided by EJB(Session bean) 2.x from Spring?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should spring doc. Accesing to EJB is possible.
[link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/ejb.html)

Comment: Thanks for U R response.But , EJB is heavy weight component and spring is light weight, how does it possible?